# TensorFlow mandatory GPU use

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

Our GPUs are in exclusive mode. Sometimes some user may manually login a machine and steals a GPU.

How can I raise an exception whenever GPU initialization fails in a TensorFlow script? I noticed that when TensorFlow is unable to initialize the GPU, it prints out an error message but runs on CPU. I want to stop it instead of running on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

If you force any part of your graph to run on a GPU using:

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
```

then your session variables initializer will stop running and throw an `InvalidArgumentError` when no GPU is available.